# How to check if array values are almost same

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have an array that contains seven numbers:

```
array(159.60, 159.60, 159.60, 159.60, 159.60, 199.50, 199.50);
array(395.68, 395.68, 395.68, 395.68, 395.68, 395.68, 395.68);
array(531.18, 531.18, 531.18, 531.19, 531.18, 531.18, 531.18);
```

I need to check if all values are same, with one twist: sometimes the values differ *slightly* because of rounding off errors (see 4th value in 3rd array). I want them considered same.

What would be the best way to check if all array values are same within a tolerance value, say `0.1`.

Comment: Find the min/max elements and subtract them.

Comment: @zerkms, you can actually write that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each array we can find the `max` & `min` value and check if it is greater than `0` or not as @zerkms suggested.

```
$tests = array(
    array(159.60, 159.60, 159.60, 159.60, 159.60, 199.50, 199.50), 
    array(395.68, 395.68, 395.68, 395.68, 395.68, 395.68, 395.68), 
    array(531.18, 531.18, 531.18, 531.19, 531.18, 531.18, 531.18)
);
foreach ($tests as $i => $test) {
    $result = abs(max($test) - min($test)) <= 0.1;
    var_dump($result);
}
```

**Output**

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

[CODE](https://eval.in/482106)

Comment: That's funny you decided to *remove* credits to me :-D (not that it was important to me - but I find it curious that you initially put them then removed)

Comment: @zerkms I was updating the answers with some descriptions. You can see it now. Hope you get it.. :)

Comment: Not `0`, but should be like: `(max($ar) - min($ar)) <= tolerance`

Comment: What are you doing...@Sougata? Not `>0`, but `<=tolerance`

Comment: @vish4071 For those values it comparing correctly. if it needs more smaller value then `0` can be replaced with that.

Comment: @zerkms then the output needs to be reversed. :).

Comment: I'm off. I'm not even sure why something that takes 30 seconds to implement needs a 20 minutes discussion :-D

Answer (score -1):

You could write a pretty simple loop to check this:

```
function withinTolerance($array,$tolerance){
    $initialValue = $array[0]; //Set the initial value
    foreach ($array as $num){
        //Loop the array, and if the value is outside the tolerance, return false.
        if ($num < $initialValue - $tolerance || $num > $initialValue + $tolerance) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This solution is broken: the 0-th element does not have any special properties so that you could rely on it.

Comment: bad answer. Say, `tolerance=1`, array= {5,6,4,5,5,5,5}. Your function returns true...it should, false.

Comment: @SalmanA well, why not with element with index `1` or `42`? What is the maths behind this magic: `$num < $initialValue - $tolerance`?

Comment: @SalmanA are you sure you have come through all the comments to this answer?

Comment: @SalmanA not sure what "incorrect" means. The second comment perfectly demonstrates the implementation flaw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97270/discussion-between-salman-a-and-zerkms).

Comment: It fails for `{6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}` with tolerance of 1.